# [android.manifest]: withAndroidManifestBaseMod: androidManifest.manifest.hasOwnProperty is not a function

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to build in expo (EAS). But getting this error. I think I am missing something in the app.json or app.config.json. Stuck on this for a week now. Thanks in advance.

**Error code**

`expo:config-plugins:android:package Found package "com.sh411.CFlow" for type "debug" +0ms
expo:config-plugins:android:package Found package "com.sh411.CFlow" for type "main" +1ms
expo:config-plugins:android:package Found package "com.sh411.CFlow" for type "release" +0ms
android.dangerous: withAndroidExpoPlugins ➜ withPlugins ➜ withStaticPlugin ➜ withAndroidIcons ➜ withDangerousMod

- Config syncing
  android.dangerous: withAndroidExpoPlugins ➜ withPlugins ➜ withStaticPlugin ➜ withGoogleServicesFile ➜ withDangerousMod
- Config syncing
  android.dangerous: withSplashScreen ➜ withAndroidSplashScreen ➜ withPlugins ➜ withStaticPlugin ➜ withAndroidSplashDrawables ➜ withDangerousMod
- Config syncing
  android.dangerous: withSplashScreen ➜ withAndroidSplashScreen ➜ withPlugins ➜ withStaticPlugin ➜ withAndroidSplashImages ➜ withDangerousMod
- Config syncing
  android.dangerous: withFallback ➜ withPlugins ➜ withStaticPlugin ➜ withNotificationIcons ➜ withDangerousMod
- Config syncing
  android.manifest: withDefaultBaseMods ➜ withAndroidBaseMods ➜ withGeneratedBaseMods ➜ withAndroidManifestBaseMod
- Config syncing
  expo:config-plugins:base-mods mods.android.manifest: file path: /Users/sh/CFlowMobile/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml +83ms
  android.manifest: withAndroidExpoPlugins ➜ withPlugins ➜ withStaticPlugin ➜ withAndroidIcons ➜ withAndroidManifestIcons ➜ withAndroidManifest
- Config syncing
  **android.manifest: withAndroidExpoPlugins ➜ withPlugins ➜ withStaticPlugin ➜ withPermissions ➜ withAndroidManifest
- Config syncing
  ✖ Config sync failed**

TypeError: [android.manifest]: withAndroidManifestBaseMod: androidManifest.manifest.hasOwnProperty is not a function
TypeError: [android.manifest]: withAndroidManifestBaseMod: androidManifest.manifest.hasOwnProperty is not a function
at setAndroidPermissions (/Users/sh/CFlowMobile/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/android/Permissions.js:123:33)`

**app.config.js**

```
    module.exports = {
      expo: {
        name: 'CFlow',
        slug: 'CFlow',
        version: '1.0.0',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        icon: './assets/icon.png',
        android: {
          package: 'com.sh411.CFlow',
          manifest: {
            permissions: ['CAMERA', 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'],
            usesCleartextTraffic: true,
            application: {
              activity: {
                'android:windowSoftInputMode': 'adjustPan',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        ios: {
          bundleIdentifier: 'com.sh411.CFlow',
        },
        androidStatusBar: {
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          barStyle: 'dark-content',
          translucent: true,
        },
        splash: {
          image: './assets/splash.png',
          resizeMode: 'contain',
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        },
        mods: {
          android: {
            manifest: {
              permissions: ['CAMERA', 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'],
              usesCleartextTraffic: true,
              application: {
                activity: {
                  'android:windowSoftInputMode': 'adjustPan',
                },
              },
            },
          },
          ios: {
            infoPlist: {
              NSCameraUsageDescription: 'This app uses the camera to take photos',
              NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription: 'This app needs access to your photo library',
            },
          },
        },
        extra: {
          eas: {
            projectId: 'b1c7ca55-d671-4f7b-a550-xxx',
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

Tried changing the app.json and app.config.json and updating the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you got this figured out, but in case others stumble across this. I had the same error caused by an older version of xml2js. See this article. https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/670. xml2js fixes this issue in version 6.1. In my case I used a yarn resolution to install the latest version.